# how to start reading at line X in python?

Tags: python

actually I read a file like this:

```
f = open("myfile.txt")
for line in f:
    #do s.th. with the line
```

what do I need to do to start reading not at the first line, but at the X line? (e.g. the 5.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An opened file object `f` is an iterator. Read (and throw away) the first four lines and then go on with regular reading:

```
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as f:
    for i in xrange(4):
        next(f, None)
    for line in f:
        #do s.th. with the line
```

Comment: `next(f, None)` to not raise an error for files less than 4 lines

Answer (score 9):

Using [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) you can specify start, stop and step if needs be and apply that to your input file...

```
from itertools import islice

with open('yourfile') as fin:
    for line in islice(fin, 5, None):
        pass
```

Comment: This is what itertools.islice was made for